# Flutter : About error handling of timeout when retrieving documents of Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making an app with Flutter (Dart) and Firebase.

```
displayName = (await instance.collection('users').doc(ds.id).get())
              .data()['displayName'];
```

When retrieving the Firestore document as described above, for example,
if I cannot get it after waiting 10 seconds,
I want to set the displayName to '' (empty string).
How should I write if I want to do something like that?

```
        try {
          Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:5,),(){
            throw Exception('eeeeeewwwwwwwww');
          });
          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:10),);

          //When I actually execute the code of ↓, 
          //there are almost no cases where it takes time to acquire (it can be acquired in a short time), 
          //so I tried to write a pseudo case like ↑ that can not be acquired.
          /*
          displayName = (await instance.collection('users').doc(ds.id).get())
              .data()['displayName'];
          url = (await instance.collection('users').doc(ds.id).get())
              .data()['photoUrl'];
          */
        }catch(e){
          displayName='time out';
          url=null;
          continue;//(← Since it is in a for statement, if it takes 10 seconds or more, I want to skip to the next loop.)
        }
```

The above code came to my mind, and I thought I could do it, but when I actually executed it,
The exception is thrown, but the catch clause is not executed (the exception was not caught).

I'm not sure why this doesn't work, but why not?
Is there a theory method for such cases?

When I googled, it says that when we use Dio, we can handle such timeout error by just setting the number of seconds (because it is in English, we can only understand the rough atmosphere).
However, the reason why people say "Dio looks good" is that if we don't use Dio, we have to write this kind of processing ourself, but with Dio we can easily do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this although I haven't tested the code:

```dart
Future<String> fetchOrSetUser() async {
  final String displayName;

  try {
    final userRef = await instance.collection('users').doc(ds.id).get().timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));

    displayName = userRef.data()['displayName'];
  } on TimeoutException catch (error) {
    await instance.collection('users').doc(ds.id).update({
       'displayName': ''
    });

    displayName = '';
  } catch (error, _) {
     rethrow;
  }

  return displayName;
}
```

It sets a timeout on the async call of 10 seconds and then tries to catch the TimeoutException. If that happens, it updates the userRef's displayName in the on TimeoutException block. I'm not sure if this would also fail if the user has no internet but I think updates can be written without internet... ?

Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I'm sorry, but I don't have time to check the results right away.
We will report the result after confirmation.